# PyQt5 - Push window into foreground over fullscreen window

Tags: python-3.x, desktop-application, pyqt5

I would like to create a little window announcer program for computer gamers, which would display third-party data to the users.

Trouble comes when I want it to be displayed in foreground over active fullscreen window, which is computer game. Announcing program and the game should be started both separately. I would like to achieve something like this:

[image]

This is my code. I used `QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint` which should do the job, but looks like it does not. After the fullscreen game is focused by user, game is immediately pushed into foreground in front of my little window not matter what. I have very little experience over Windows OS:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)


class Modals(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.move(20, 50)
        self.setFixedSize(175, 85)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Modals()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Question**:

Is there any way, application GUI can be in the exclusive foreground until it is shut down by user using PyQt5?